# LLVM code generation from AST memory error

Tags: c, compiler-construction, llvm, bison

I have this AST structure, which fills in parser.c generated by Bison.
First of all, dummy code I try to compile:

```
start
int a;
a = 5;
end
```

AST:

```
struct ASTNode {
    NodeType type;       
    LLVMValueRef llvmValue;
    union {
        int intValue;                            
        double doubleValue;                     
        bool boolValue;                          
        char *identifier;                       
        struct BinaryOpNode binaryOp;            
        struct AssignmentNode assignment;        
        struct VariableDeclarationNode variableDeclaration; 
    } data;
};
```

I setup llvm like this:

```
void setupLLVM() {
LLVMInitializeNativeTarget();
LLVMInitializeNativeAsmPrinter();
LLVMInitializeNativeAsmParser();

GlobalContext = LLVMContextCreate();
GlobalModule = LLVMModuleCreateWithNameInContext("test_module", GlobalContext);
GlobalBuilder = LLVMCreateBuilderInContext(GlobalContext); }
```

This is ast.c which contains actual code:

```
ASTNode* createVariableDeclarationNode(char *type, char *identifier) {
    ASTNode* node = malloc(sizeof(ASTNode));
    node->type = AST_VARIABLE_DECLARATION;
    node->data.variableDeclaration.type = _strdup(type);
    node->data.variableDeclaration.identifier = _strdup(identifier);
    
    LLVMTypeRef varType = 0;

    if (strcmp(type, "int") == 0) {
        varType = LLVMInt32TypeInContext(GlobalContext);
    }
    else if (strcmp(type, "double") == 0) {
        varType = LLVMDoubleTypeInContext(GlobalContext);
    }
    else if (strcmp(type, "bool") == 0) {
        varType = LLVMInt1TypeInContext(GlobalContext);
    }

    LLVMValueRef var = LLVMAddGlobal(GlobalModule, varType, identifier);
    LLVMSetInitializer(var, LLVMConstInt(varType, 0, 0));
    node->llvmValue = var;

    printNode(node);
    return node;
}
```

And code for generate const int node:

```
ASTNode* createIntNode(int value) {
    ASTNode* node = malloc(sizeof(ASTNode));
    node->type = AST_INTEGER;
    node->data.intValue = value;
    node->llvmValue = LLVMConstInt(LLVMInt32TypeInContext(GlobalContext), value, 0);
    printNode(node);
    return node;
}
```

Now, when I want to do assignment a = 5 I do this:

```
ASTNode* createAssignmentNode(char *identifier, ASTNode *expression) {
    ASTNode* node = malloc(sizeof(ASTNode));
    node->type = AST_ASSIGNMENT;
    node->data.assignment.identifier = _strdup(identifier);
    node->data.assignment.expression = expression;
    LLVMValueRef var = LLVMGetNamedGlobal(GlobalModule, identifier);

    if (!var || !expression->llvmValue) {
        printf("assigment error\n");
    }
    // CRASH
    node->llvmValue = LLVMBuildStore(GlobalBuilder, expression->llvmValue, var);
  
    printNode(node);
    return node;
}
```

But in node->llvmValue = LLVMBuildStore(GlobalBuilder, expression->llvmValue, var);
I've got the exception with error read in 0x0000000000000050 address:
call stack:

[image]

Local vars:

[image]

Plese help me find cause of error.

Comment: Is passing `NULL` as the last two arguments to `LLVMBuildStore()` like you do in `LLVMBuildStore(GlobalBuilder, expression->llvmValue, var);` defined behavior?

Comment: @Harith why u think it's `NULL`? In my Local Vars screen this vars are defined.

Comment: I was asking generally, because `if (!var || !expression->llvmValue) { printf("assigment error\n"); }` would allow a `NULL` pointer to be passed to `LLVMBuildStore()`, which may or may not be defined behavior.

Comment: @Harith yes this is an misstake in If statement but nvm

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out. My setupLLVM was wrong. Now it's

```
void setupLLVM() {
    LLVMInitializeNativeTarget();
    LLVMInitializeNativeAsmPrinter();
    LLVMInitializeNativeAsmParser();

    GlobalContext = LLVMContextCreate();
    GlobalModule = LLVMModuleCreateWithNameInContext("test_module", GlobalContext);
    GlobalBuilder = LLVMCreateBuilderInContext(GlobalContext);

    LLVMTypeRef mainFuncType = LLVMFunctionType(LLVMVoidTypeInContext(GlobalContext), NULL, 0, 0);
    LLVMValueRef mainFunc = LLVMAddFunction(GlobalModule, "main", mainFuncType);

    LLVMBasicBlockRef entry = LLVMAppendBasicBlockInContext(GlobalContext, mainFunc, "entry");
    LLVMPositionBuilderAtEnd(GlobalBuilder, entry);
}
```

I need to create module for my own. (EP).